# ASP.NET pressing Enter key causes log out

Tags: asp.net

I have created Website. After I login When I hit enter key for add Product, my Website just kick me out.? I dont have problem with adding  my cart with mouse click. Does Any One have same Issue or Any suggestion ..

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you getting any errors?  We need a lot more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your controls inside an ASP:Panel and make your AddProduct Button as Default Button:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAddProduct"">
            //Your Other Stuff
           <asp:Button ID="btnAddProduct" runat="server" onclick="btnAddProduct_Click"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

This will Fire AddProduct Button when you hit enter.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach I found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/338481/how-can-we-solved-enter-key-logout-problem-on-text) - if you don't want to add a panel

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDisableEnter" runat="server" Text="" 
            OnClientClick="return false;" style="display: none;" />
<form id="form1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnDisableEnter">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Master Page in asp.net C# and if you are using a button for logout, please type in Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="logout" 
         UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Use `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` in your master page. That's how my problem was solved.